# Is that possible get the number from a string when it inclund a keyword?

Tags: javascript, string

I have several sentences,for example: 
the price is 20.3
the size is 20.3

I want use Java Script to get the number when find the price keyword in those sentences.

As I know

```
x = "the price is 20.3"
y = x.otherTotal.replace(/[^0-9]/ig,"")
```

can get the number, but when sentence change to

```
x = "the size is 20.3"
```

i don't want return the number.

Comment: your question isnt very clear, but I believe you can achieve it by using regexp and match functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `includes` to check for `price` keyword.

```js
x = "the price is 20.3";

const regex = /[0-9.0-9]+/;

if(x.includes("price")) {
    console.log(x.match(regex)[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for `price` and then get the number.

```js
function getPrice(s) {
    return /price/i.test(s) && s.match(/\d+\.\d*/)[0];
}

console.log(getPrice("the price is 20.3"));
console.log(getPrice("the size is 20.3"));
```

Answer (score 1):

So match the entire string

```js
const x1 = "the price is 20.3"
const x2 = "the size is 20.3"

function getPrice (str) {
  //const match = str.match(/price[^\d]*(\d+\.\d+)$/) // or just was price before numbers
  const match = str.match(/^the price is (\d+\.\d+)$/)
  return match && match[1]
}

console.log(x1, getPrice(x1))
console.log(x2, getPrice(x2))
```

Comment: I think he's after something more generic ->  `when find the price keyword`

Answer (score 0):

1) check if if it includes the word
2) Split it 
3) Take the last Item

```
x.includes('price')?x.split(' ')[x.split(' ').length-1]:false
```